# Django background tasks wait for result

Tags: python, django, heroku, background-task

I am trying to run a some machine learning computation task in the background due to heroku's 30 seconds timeout. I was trying to implement django-background-tasks. here's my code:

```
def process_data(request):
    symbol = request.GET.get('symbol')
    data = test1.now(symbol)
    print(data)
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)


@background(schedule=0)
    def test1(symbol):
    symbol = symbol+'ksksk'
    #long running machine learning stuff
    return symbol
```

I displaying a loading screen while i wait for the computations to be completed and then return the data using jsonresponse. But when i print the data it show of type instead of the data i need:

```
<class 'background_task.models.Task'>
```

how do i get the data which i have computed in the background to the original view so that i can display the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background tasks are usually asynchronous, meaning the process will run on the background. Expecting an instant result from your request does not make any sense in my opinion. It would make more sense to receive eg. 201 created, notifying the user that the request has been received and will be processed.

When the application is processing it, it could write the result to the database and expose the result over an API or interface.

```
app.com/run-computation?symbol=something # 201 Created

# (API)view
def run_computation(request):
    symbol = request.GET.get('symbol')
    data = compute.now(symbol)

    return JsonResponse({"201"}, safe=True)

# Task
@background(schedule=0)
def compute(symbol):
    # Do a lot of exciting stuff
    result = this_will_take_a_while(symbol)

    # Write result to database so it can be exposed
    ComputeResult.objects.create(symbol=symbol, result=result)

    # Most likely this task will not return anything, since the result
    # is stored when completed and exposed elsewhere. When it fails
    # it is stored in the Task object:
    # @see: https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/blob/master/background_task/models.py#L206
```

When the computation is finished and the result is available it could be exposed:

```
# (API)view
def get_results():
   results = ComputeResult.objects.all()
   return JsonResponse(serialize_results(results))

app.com/results/
[{
    "symbol": "something",
    "result": [...]
},
{
    "symbol": "interesting",
    "result": [...]
}]
```

The object you are currently returning is an internal object that contains the information for django-background-tasks how to process the asynchronous task.

Comment: Okay, I think I am kind of with you... The idea is to return status code 201 after the process initiates... So then on the client side, you (could) keep sending xml ajax requests to update the status of said process, until it is finished... to then kick of something on the client and / or server, right?

Comment: I think there are many different approaches on handling background tasks and processing the feedback or follow-up on job success or failure. This mainly depends on the implementation, requirements and used backend for task processing. Polling, sockets, sending an email can all be a method to update on a status of a job. This example only shows a simple concept, you should find the appropriate flow for your use-case.